# How to get 'most commented posts' in Doctrine?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, dql

I have Post entity. Post entity have one Category, many Tags and many Comments.

How to get 'most commented posts' ordered by most commented?

When I am doing this:

```
$query = $this->createQueryBuilder('post')
    ->addSelect('COUNT(comments.id) AS HIDDEN comments_num')
    ->innerJoin('post.comments', 'comments')
    ->groupBy('post.id')
    ->orderBy('comments_num', 'DESC')
    ->addOrderBy('post.created', 'DESC')
    ->getQuery()
;
```

it is working but Doctrine makes so many queries, but the problem is the more comments the more queries *times something... It cant be that way. On the page with this query results I have 71 queries and the number of them grows with commented posts number.

When I am doing the same but adding left joining and selecting category, tags and comments there... queries number is low and independent from comments number but when I pass that query to Paginator it gets kind of empty pages after few pages with results...

```
$query = $this->createQueryBuilder('post')
    ->addSelect('category, tags, comments')
    ->addSelect('COUNT(c) AS HIDDEN comments_num')
    ->innerJoin('post.comments', 'c')
    ->innerJoin('post.comments', 'comments')
    ->leftJoin('post.category', 'category')
    ->leftJoin('post.tags', 'tags')
    ->groupBy('post.id')
    ->addGroupBy('tags.id')
    ->addGroupBy('comments.id')
    ->orderBy('comments_num', 'DESC')
    ->addOrderBy('post.created', 'DESC')
    ->getQuery()
;
```

query will be passed to Paginator so it must be build in DQL or using QueryBuilder.

**edit:**
I think there is a bug in Paginator, because... When I dump that second query results I am getting good results in array collection of 12. But when I pass that query to Paginator and then call Paginator.count() I get results: 55 :D when there are 44 posts in test database :)

Comment: I think i could help you but to be sure what doctrine does it would be helpful if you could add the DQL-String (`...->getQuery()->getDQL()`) to your question. As far as i know, doctrine allways creates a DQL even when using the QueryBuilder and then transforms that to SQL...

Answer (score 0):

In The first moment Write your query just with SQL, after do you can execute pure SQL in doctrine.

After you try convert your SQL for DQL